# Styles based on Normal display a white background, unrelated to the Borders & Shading

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, styles, cells

In Word, when I write text in a table cell with a colored background, I see a white background behind my text. I supposed it had something to do with the Border & Shading options, but it was already set on "no color". To make sure this was unrelated to this option, I picked a green color for the Shading. Now I have three levels of background: the cell background (which is normal), the green Shading background that I just selected, and the white color behind my text.

[image: the example described above]

I know this has something to do with my style, because when I picked another style, I see the problem being solved for any style NOT based on Normal style, and the problem remains for any style (heading, custom style, etc.) that will be be based on Normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [video](https://youtu.be/NwaNyq7BxEU), you'll see how to set the shading on a text level. But since this only covers the text level and not the other levels, let me explain a bit more here.

Keep in mind, that you can have multiple layers of shading:

- table cell
- paragraph
- single characters / text

Here is an example I created:

[image]

You will see, that there is a grey table cell shading, a blue paragraph shading and an orange text shading.

And as you already mentioned correctly, you can set all of this in the "Border and Shading" options (there in the "Shading" tab):

[image]

It is important to note, that the "Apply to" dropdown will only show the "Text" option, if you really **selected text**! If no text is selected and the cursor is simply in the table cell, then it **won't** show!